# How to find the split in the given set of numbers.

Tags: real-numbers, sorting

Beforehand I would like to express apologies if this sort of question is not suited here, but I desperately need it answered.

I have a set of numbers:

> [2, 5, 6, 2, 2, 81, 72, 77]

From the above set, we can say that certain numbers above can be "grouped" together. Such that:

> [2, 5, 6, 2, 2]

and

> [81, 72, 77]

My question is how do I obtain the above two groupings? Is there an algorithm or formulae to achieve this?

Comment: Do you know in advance how many groups you will have? If so, you can use some of the standard clustering algorithms like $k$-means clustering.

Comment: The term you should look up is "cluster analysis". In general it's a hard problem to specify, and it's often hard to solve once it's been well-specified.

Comment: Suppose there can be any number of samples in the set. But ultimately what I want is to split the set in such a way that the numbers all lie closest to a certain "mean".

Comment: @randem_gen_guy: What I'm asking is not how many numbers would be in the set to begin with, nor how many numbers will wind up in each group after you've grouped them. What I'm asking is do you know in advance how many groups you want to group your numbers into? In your example, two groups totally makes sense. Do you know beforehand how many groups you will need?

Comment: Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering.

Comment: @AdrianKeister What I know is that there will definitely be EXACTLY two groups.

Comment: Are you trying to minimize the difference between the mean of the group and the values? Do you know the range of numbers?

Comment: @PeterChikov All I want is to simply separate the numbers that are the most "similar" to each-other into two different groups. Its obvious above that  2, 5, 6, 2, 2 is different as a group from 81, 72, 77, what I want to know is how to separate them. I do not know the range of numbers.

Comment: If you know there will be exactly two groups, then use $k$-means.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. As mentioned in the comments below my question, many people were recommending the K-Means algorithm. It worked perfectly!